# Python: Delaunay triangle vertices don't "line up" when saved as .pdf or .png

Tags: python, matplotlib, delaunay

I created a set of Delaunay triangles using scipy.spatial.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
from skimage import io
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from scipy.ndimage import rotate

h = 700
w = 700
npts = 500
pts = np.zeros((npts,2))
pts[:,0] = np.random.randint(0,w,npts)
pts[:,1] = np.random.randint(0,h,npts)

tri = Delaunay(pts)
centers = np.sum(pts[tri.simplices], axis=1, dtype='int')/3.0

#plt.figure()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.xlim(0, w)
plt.ylim(0, h)


for i in range(0,len(pts[tri.simplices])-1):
    temp_tri = plt.Polygon(pts[tri.simplices][i], color = colors[i]/256) #colors variable is a numpy.ndarray variable that contains RGB values
    plt.gca().add_patch(temp_tri)

plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
plt.axis('off')

plt.savefig('test.pdf', bbox_inches = 'tight', dpi=fig.dpi)
plt.show()
```

On the screen, the output is as I intended. However, when I save it as pdf or png, the vertices of Delaunay triangles do not match (they do when I look at them through plt.show())

The picture below is part of the whole picture, just to highlight where the vertices don't match.

[image: Delaunay triangles with vertices that do not match.]

Few suggestions I found with issues regarding different images shown with plt.show() and fitsave() said I should match the dpi, which I have done.

Please advise on what I should try. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: If I should apply different techniques to save a plot of delaunay triangles, I'm all ears!! I'm just very confused right now. Thank you!

Comment: The code you show has 500 points, but the image shows 6 triangles? I think I'm confused as well.

Comment: Also `Delaunay(np.zeros((500,2)))` is pretty useless, asit will not create any triangles at all. Can you please provide a [mcve], so this issue can be reproduced?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest 
Sorry, I forgot to mention that the picture I posted is a zoomed in version to highlight the problem I'm dealing with.

Also, added couple more lines of code to make it more reproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell the reason why it fails to produce the correct points for the triangles, but in general it's probably better to create a `PolyCollection` from the vertices, instead of individual triangles.

In that case the problem would not appear.

```
pc = PolyCollection(pts[tri.simplices], 
                    facecolors=np.random.rand(len(pts[tri.simplices]),3),
                    edgecolor="face",linewidth=0.1)
plt.gca().add_collection(pc)
```

[image]

Here some remaining overlap is seen, which is due to the linewidth. Smaller linewidths would look better in the pdf, e.g. `linewidth=0.01`, but might result in "white" lines in the graphics on screen. You may play around with that parameter until you are happy with the result.

[image]

Comment: This brings me closer to where I want to go! Thanks so much!!